# How do I add text to a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm making a java Text Editior and I can't seems to know how to insert a line of text that is "[code][/code]" Here is what I'm trying to program. The method for the inserting is called "insert". So it has to be something that is insert,(something that inserts strings of text in `JTextArea`)

```
/////////////////// CODE //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

this.insert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        }
    });
/////////////// END OF CODE ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Please go through this 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: try using method <textarea>.setText("your text");

Comment: What is `insert`? Are you assigning `ActionListener` to a *method*?

Comment: `textArea.append(text)`

Comment: Yes insert is a button on JMenuItem that is assigned to ActionListener

Comment: You haven't actually specified what you want to happen when you click this menu item

Comment: your code peeskillet didn't work

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal example in the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) itself.

Answer (score 2):

Simple example to set/assign text to JTextArea .. this is not the solution but it will help you...

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(
    "This is an editable JTextArea. " +
    "A text area is a \"plain\" text component, " +
    "which means that although it can display text " +
    "in any font, all of the text is in the same font."
);
textArea.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 16));
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Although to set the text .. use this method

```
void insert(String str, int pos) 
Inserts the specified text at the specified position.

public void setText(String t)
Sets the text of JTextArea
```

For refrerence and help please follow [jtextareaguide](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/components/40textarea/25ex-textarea.html)

Link to [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1IZdKCjTgg)

Guide for [Simple Editor](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/examples/components/editor/nutpad.html) in Java

Answer (score 2):

Java already provides a method for inserting text in the JTextArea class. Try this...

```
 JTextArea t = new JTextArea();
 t.setText("specified string");
 t.append("+ added string");
```

Comment: didn't work none of your guys answers worked. ;( Halp me

Comment: @user3295645 Guess I am not understanding the question do you mean you wish to insert the text you have above written as code into the JTextArea?

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
JTextArea text=new JTextArea();
  text.setText("Message..");
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) is a doc.

```
public class JTextArea extends JTextComponent
```

A `JTextArea` is a multi-line area that displays plain text. It is intended to be a lightweight component that provides source compatibility with the java.awt.TextArea class where it can reasonably do so. You can find information and examples of using all the text components in Using Text Components, a section in The Java Tutorial.

Comment: i guess [that](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-jtextarea-class-example) site would help you..with best example to clear your doubts..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JTextArea textj1 = new JTextArea();
textj1.setText(textj1.getText().trim() + "a string or even an arraylist");
```

Answer (score 0):

Better using:

```
textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+" Message");
```